# Access Context Menu

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to access the Context Menu UI AutomationElement of Notepad, however I am struggling to do so:

```
Imports System.Windows.Automation
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module AutomateNotepad
    Sub Main()
        Dim wNotepad, document As AutomationElement
        wNotepad = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Untitled - Notepad"))

        document = wNotepad.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "document"))
        document.SetFocus()

        SendKeys.SendWait("+{F10}")

        context = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "context"))
        While context Is Nothing
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to get context again")
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            context = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "context"))
        End While

        MsgBox("Found it!")

    End Sub
End Module
```

My problem is that when I run the application, the notepad context menu opens but UIAutomation never appears to get the AutomationElement of it...

This is a screenshot from Inspect.exe:

[image: Inspect Image]

Given the inspect picture and the structure it presents, I see no reason why this would be occurring... Does anyone know where I might be going wrong?

P.S. I'm very new to VB.NET but have been working with VBA for 2-3 years so I apologise for any bad habits I may have...

Comment: If using .net please get rid of the `GoTo` statements...

Comment: Any reason for this...?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Its about control flow as well as it can make code difficult to read and maintain. They by no means are evil, its the misuse of `GoTo` I have seen... `If`, `Case` etc would justify your conditions... Currently the way your code flow is now, it will just keep looping `until context` ***is*** something, but it will never be `Not Nothing` because the code is wrong, you may possibly receive a `StackOverflowException` eventually.

Comment: Interesting... Personally I find: 'https://puu.sh/v5GtJ/6ec9dfa01d.png' revolting...

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution to my issue. The trick is to subscribe to UIAutomation OpenMenuEvent. To do this I created a `ContextWatcher` class:

```
Public Class ContextWatcher
    Public Shared Menu As AutomationElement
    Private Shared _EventHandler As AutomationEventHandler
    Public Shared Sub trackContext()
        _EventHandler = New AutomationEventHandler(AddressOf OnContextOpened)
        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(AutomationElement.MenuOpenedEvent, AutomationElement.RootElement, TreeScope.Descendants, _EventHandler)
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub untrackContext()
        Automation.RemoveAutomationEventHandler(AutomationElement.MenuOpenedEvent, AutomationElement.RootElement, _EventHandler)
    End Sub
    Private Shared Sub OnContextOpened(src As Object, args As AutomationEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Menu opened.")
        Dim element = TryCast(src, AutomationElement)
        If element Is Nothing Then
            Return
        Else
            Menu = element
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

To access the context menu I can use this:

```
ContextWatcher.trackContext()

SendKeys.SendWait("+{F10}")

Dim context As AutomationElement
context = ContextWatcher.Menu
While context Is Nothing
    Console.WriteLine("Trying to get context again")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    context = ContextWatcher.Menu
End While

' Do Stuff with context menu

ContextWatcher.untrackContext()
Imports System.Windows.Automation
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module AutomateNotepad
    Sub Main()
        Dim wNotepad, document As AutomationElement

        'Get 'Untitled - Notepad' main window
        wNotepad = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Untitled - Notepad"))

        'Get Notepad document element
        document = wNotepad.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "document"))

        'Set focus to document
        document.SetFocus()

        'Start watching for context menu
        ContextWatcher.trackContext()

        'Open context menu
        SendKeys.SendWait("+{F10}")

        'Get context menu from ContextWatcher class
        Dim context As AutomationElement
        context = ContextWatcher.Menu
        While context Is Nothing
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to get context again")
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            context = ContextWatcher.Menu
        End While

        'trigger undo
        invokeContextMenuItem(context, "Undo")

        'Stop watching for context menu
        ContextWatcher.untrackContext()
    End Sub

    Sub invokeContextMenuItem(context As AutomationElement, sMenuItem As String)
        'Get context menu children
        Dim controls As AutomationElementCollection = context.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)

        'Loop over controls to find control with name sMenuItem
        Dim control As AutomationElement
        For Each control In controls
            If control.Current.Name = sMenuItem Then
                'Invoke control
                getInvokePattern(control).Invoke()
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    'Helper function to get InvokePattern from UI Element
    Function getInvokePattern(element As AutomationElement) As InvokePattern
        Return element.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern)
    End Function

    Public Class ContextWatcher
        Public Shared Menu As AutomationElement
        Private Shared _EventHandler As AutomationEventHandler
        Public Shared Sub trackContext()
            _EventHandler = New AutomationEventHandler(AddressOf OnContextOpened)
            Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(AutomationElement.MenuOpenedEvent, AutomationElement.RootElement, TreeScope.Descendants, _EventHandler)
        End Sub
        Public Shared Sub untrackContext()
            Automation.RemoveAutomationEventHandler(AutomationElement.MenuOpenedEvent, AutomationElement.RootElement, _EventHandler)
        End Sub
        Private Shared Sub OnContextOpened(src As Object, args As AutomationEventArgs)
            Console.WriteLine("Menu opened.")
            Dim element = TryCast(src, AutomationElement)
            If element Is Nothing Then
                Return
            Else
                Menu = element
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Module
```